# smallest checksum on a string

Tags: php, hash, unique

scratching my head over this.

i have 350 strings average 90 chars long, all strings are unique.
Now, i wanna generate a unique id for each string.

i tried the sum of chars in the string wich gave two doubles, the returned sum
is not unique enough. Anybody any idea how to approach this? I thought of hash(), is that the best solution?

abcdef will return the same as abcdfe

Comment: Depending on whether you know the possible strings or not, either Bill's answer or or Ignacio's would be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a fixed set of strings and you will only need to look those up then find a minimal perfect hash function. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function

Answer (score 1):

Checksums and hashes will never be unique. Call the first string "1" and go from there.